# PHP Multiply String Values from service

Tags: php

I'm trying to multiply a value (sales tax) that is being returned from a service. I'm able to 'add' it without any problems, but I'm not able to get it to multiply using my string:

```
floatval(($service->PRICE)+floatval($service->SALES_TAX)+floatval($service->TRAVEL))
```

I've tried using:

```
floatval(($service->PRICE)*floatval($service->SALES_TAX)+floatval($service->TRAVEL))
```

and also

```
floatval(($service->PRICE*$service->SALES_TAX)+floatval($service->TRAVEL))
```

But both only return the Travel amount, instead of the Price * Sales Tax + Travel.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are those values and what's the result? There should also be no need to call `floatval` that often, the values will be cast to numeric types automatically.

Comment: have you tried to display the values of price and sales tax already? it might be that they are having a null value or 0 on any of those variables

Comment: @ChristopherPelayo: Agreed, `$service->SALES_TAX = 0`?

Comment: The value of SALES_TAX is 0.06 and when added it just puts .06 after the price which already has the travel added in.

Comment: Travel and Sales Tax are being returned in hidden fields but should be added and multiplied (respectively) to the price that is displayed to the user.

Comment: if sales tax is .06 how much is the sample price? just want to follow the real flow of your code since it's returning the values that you really need

Comment: wait a sec how about if you try this not really a good practice though:

floatval((floatval($service->PRICE)*floatval($service->SALES_TAX))+floatval($service->TRAVEL))

cause it might be possible that 0.06 is rounded off to 0 though during the multiplication operation

Comment: I just realized I had numberformat before the first floatval. I removed that and just used your suggestion and now am getting the travel and sales tax (it is multiplying) but no price.  So, for instance, the returned value is now $259.70 which I think is just the travel ($200) and the sales tax.

Comment: Have tried this but it is ignoring the sales tax:  number_format(floatval(($service->PRICE)*($service->SALES_TAX))+($service->PRICE)+($service->TRAVEL),2)